# How to use the same table twice with find list but with different displayFields in cakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a CountriesTable where I can find, between others, the fields 'name' and 'currency'.

Currently, I have the following Tables definitions:

```
class ProducsTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('products');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Productprices', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('Countries', [
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        ]);

    }
}

class ProductpricesTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('productprices');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        ]);

    }
}
```

class CountriesTable extends Table {

```
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('countries');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('Productprices', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        ]);

    }
}
```

So I have a product which has country as origin and a list of prices associated to a currency.

When I create a product, I have the following Form:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('name', ['label' => __("Name :")]); ?>

<?= $this->Form->input('country_id', ['label' => __("Origin :")]); ?>

<?= $this->Form->input('pricelist.0.value', ['label' => __("Price :")]); ?>

<?= $this->Form->input('pricelist.0.country_id', ['label' => __("Currency :")]); ?>
```

Of course, both `input('country_id')` display a list of names whereas I'd want that the second one display a list of currencies.

How to do?

I basically though to create a copy of CountriesTable named CurrenciesTable pointing on the same table 'countries' and associate Productprices to CurrenciesTable.... but sounds strange... no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a drop-down, you have to set it's type to `select`.

```
<?= $this->Form->input('country_id', ['type' => 'select, 'label' => __("Origin :")]); ?>
```

To add options to it use:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('country_id', ['type' => 'select, 'options' => $list, 'label' => __("Origin :")]); ?>
```

`$list` must be an array. This can be called from a model with: `$this->Model->find('list');`. Use this code in your Controller. I guess you know how to do that stuff.

Good luck!

Comment: Exact Bob, that's thé way to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @caBBAlainB great! Good luck :)